# Magento 2 how to show custom block before product.info.details and after media

Tags: product, magento2.3, layout, blocks, xml

Magento 2.3.5-p2 how to show custom block before product.info.details and after media ?
[image]

```
<div class="product-info-main"></div>
<div class="product media"></div>
<div class="custom_block"></div> **//we want to show custom block section here**
<div class="product info detailed"></div>
```

I am trying like that

```
 <referenceContainer name="main">
            <container name="custom.info" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom_block" />
        </referenceContainer>
        <block class="Custim\Block\Block\Custom" name="product_page_custom"  template="custom.phtml" />
        <move element="product_page_custom" destination="custom.info" before="catalog.product.related"/>
```

it is creating a new section after product.info.details(after upsell)

```
<div class="block upsell" data-limit="0" data-shuffle="0"></div>
<div class="custom_block"></div>
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<move element="product_page_custom" destination="custom.info" after="product.info.media"/>
```

Comment: i tried that way but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

This will place the block after product media and before product info/details

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" after="product.info.media" name="product-test" template="Gaiterjones_Page::testproductblock.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

testproductblock.phtml

```
<div style="clear: both;" id="testproductblock">
    <pre>block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" after="product.info.media" name="product-test" template="Gaiterjones_Page::testproductblock.phtml"</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: it is showing after product.info.details but before product upsell,we want to show before product.info.details.

Comment: I updated the answer, you can see it working here : https://magento2.gaiterjones.com/en/affirm-water-bottle.html

Comment: it is showing after media it showing left side half section not full section

Comment: use css "clear: both" as in my example.

Comment: can we do without css?is it possible to use XML

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom.phtml here is the path

> app/design/frontend/{{YOUR THEME NAME
> HERE}}/default//Magento_Catalog/templates/custom.phtml

After add XML

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="custom.block" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom-block" before="product.info.details">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.page.custom" template="Magento_Catalog::custom.phtml" after="-" />
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
```

Also add below css

```
.custom-block {
    clear: both;
}
```